# Django 3 error - NoReverseMatch at /; Reverse for 'car_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cars/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm currently taking a tutorial on Django from an ebook. I keep getting this error despite doing what is written in the book. Maybe, I'm having an oversight and must have missed something. Can a kind person kindly help go through my code and tell me what I must have been doing wrong?
I've attached my code snippets below. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**NoReverseMatch at /**

```
Reverse for 'car_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cars/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'car_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cars/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
Exception Location: C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  C:\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:    
['D:\\Django_Tests\\CarZone_Project',
 'C:\\Python37\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Python37\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib',
 'C:\\Python37',
 'C:\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 16 Dec 2020 14:46:01 +0000
Error during template rendering
In template D:\Django_Tests\CarZone_Project\templates\base.html, error at line 0

Reverse for 'car_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cars/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
1   {% load static %}
2   
3   <!DOCTYPE html>
4   <html>
5   
6   <head>
7       <title></title>
8       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
9       <meta charset="utf-8">
10
```

**Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view**

```
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) …
▶ Local vars
D:\Django_Tests\CarZone_Project\pages\views.py in home
    return render(request, 'pages/home.html', all_data) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py in render
            return self.template.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                    return self._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in render
            return compiled_parent._render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in _render
        return self.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py in render
                result = block.nodelist.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render
                bit = node.render_annotated(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render
                    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context)) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in render_annotated
            return self.render(context) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render
            url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)) …
▶ Local vars
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix
        raise NoReverseMatch(msg) …
▶ Local vars
```

**URLS.PY:**

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cars, name='cars'),
    path('<int:id>', views.car_detail, name='car_detail'),
]
```

**HOME TEMPLATE:**

```
                              <div class="overlap-box">
                                <div class="overlap-btns-area">
                                    <div class="car-magnify-gallery">
                                        <a href="{{each_car.car_image.url}}" class="overlap-btn">
                                            <i class="fa fa-expand"></i>
                                            <img class="hidden" src="{{each_car.car_image.url}}">
                                        </a>

                                        {% if each_car.car_image_1 %}
                                        <a href="{{each_car.car_image_1.url}}" class="hidden">
                                            <img class="hidden" src="{{each_car.car_image_1.url}}">
                                        </a>
                                        {% endif%}
                                        {% if each_car.car_image_2 %}
                                        <a href="{{each_car.car_image_2.url}}" class="hidden">
                                            <img class="hidden" src="{{each_car.car_image_2.url}}">
                                        </a>
                                        {% endif%}
                                        {% if each_car.car_image_3 %}
                                        <a href="{{each_car.car_image_3.url}}" class="hidden">
                                            <img class="hidden" src="{{each_car.car_image_3.url}}">
                                        </a>
                                        {% endif%}
                                        {% if each_car.car_image_4 %}
                                        <a href="{{each_car.car_image_4.url}}" class="hidden">
                                            <img class="hidden" src="{{each_car.car_image_4.url}}">
                                        </a>
                                        {% endif%}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="detail">
                        <h1 class="title">
                            <a href="{% url 'car_detail' car.id %}">{{each_car.car_title}}</a>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="location">
                            <a href="{% url 'car_detail' car.id %}">
                                <i class="flaticon-pin"></i>{{each_car.state}}, {{each_car.city}}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

***VIEWS.PY:***

```
def car_detail(request, id):
    single_car = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=id)
    data = {
        'single_car': single_car,
    }
    return render(request, 'cars/car_detail.html', data)
```

Comment: Mac your `path('<int:id>', views.car_detail, name='car_detail'),` expects an argument `id`

Comment: ```"{% url 'car_detail' car.id %}"```, need to be ```"{% url 'car_detail' each_car.id %}"```

Comment: Thanks @ ha-neul. A clear oversight. This solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<div class="detail">
  <h1 class="title">
    <a href="{% url 'car_detail' each_car.id %}">{{each_car.car_title}}</a>
  </h1>
  <div class="location">
    <a href="{% url 'car_detail' each_car.id %}">
      <i class="flaticon-pin"></i>{{each_car.state}}, {{each_car.city}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```